# Ember.js - linkTo error on second call

Tags: ember.js

I have a problem using ember especially the linkTo helper.

Here is the : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb377/5/)

I can't make the jsfiddle work but here is a link to a running version : [running version on cloudfoundry](http://fifemberresource.cloudfoundry.com/dummy/index)

I use ember-resource.js to get data.

I have two routes, "list" and "item".

```
Ember modules :
List (controller, route, view and template)
Item (controller, route, view and template)
ItemDetail (controller, view and template) which is included with the controller helper in the Item handlebars template.
```

The problem is :
When accessing the application from the default route ("#/list") the previous link works perfectly. But when I access the application from a item route ("#/item/1"), the previous link works fine the first time and then doesn't work any more...

And I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Any help would be appreciated...
Don't hesitate to ask extra info
Thanks in advance

Note : I really appreciate ember-resource.js but the stackoverflow tag doesn't exist... Could anyone with 1500 reps create it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a bug in ember.js that's been solved but not yet released.

It's in the control helper that calls rerender on childViews... Uncommenting this line solved the problem.