# Ember.js {{linkTo}} to itself does not render

Tags: ember.js

I have a problem with a linkTo that points to itself. The actual problem is in an application that has a sidebar with a set of links. The first time a click the link the model and view is loaded and displayed properly. However on the second click the view and/or model disappear.

I've condensed the problem in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krumpi/FSd6H/2/). The index route displays a list of links and when clicking on one of the links it will display the detail. In the detail page I have a link to itself but when I click it the model does not show.

The detail template shows the content fine but note the {{firstName}} or {{lastName}}

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
  <h2>Item Content:</h2>
  {{#linkTo "item" id}}Reload me{{/linkTo}}
  {{content}}
  <ul>
     <li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

I think the issue is similar to [Ember.js - linkTo error on second call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172326/ember-js-linkto-error-on-second-call)

**Updated sample**

Here is a new example [With linkTo at the top level](http://jsfiddle.net/krumpi/FSd6H/6/)where the {{linkTo}} item is in the top level application template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{#linkTo "test" 0}}Test 0{{/linkTo}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Following @intuitivepixel solution using an action gives me [the same result](http://jsfiddle.net/krumpi/FSd6H/7/)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <a href="#" {{action reloadMe "test" 0}}>Test 0</a>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not everything can be done with the `{{linkTo}}` helper, IMO for this kind of feature (like a reload) you should go for a `{{action}}` helper instead.

First define the action that does the routing for you when called:

```
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    reloadMe: function(route, content) {
      this.transitionTo(route, content);
    }
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return {id: model.id};
  }   
});
```

And then in your template:

```
<a href="#" {{action reloadMe "test" content}}>Reload me</a>
```

See here how you could implement it: http://jsfiddle.net/FSd6H/4/

Hope it helps.

Comment: That works indeed in the demo but does not help for my original case where the linkTo is in another template (In my case the sidebar)

Comment: If your reload action is in the application template, move the reload event to the application route events hash to get the job done

Comment: That is what I did in the [third fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krumpi/FSd6H/8/). If you use the link on the lower part the model shows fine but not with the link or action on the first line